# JavaScript: How to detect a malformed URI?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

The best practice in JavaScript is to use some idiom to detect errors rather than relying on try-catch.  Easy to do with TypeError:

```
if (typeof foo !== "number") {
  console.log("That ain't a number!");
  return;
}
```

And similar idioms with ReferenceError and RangeError.

But how the heck do you test a URIError before using encodeURI() or decodeURI() without putting them in a try-catch?

(It isn't possible is an acceptable answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to manually check a URI for invalid escape characters before decoding, no? That's the only solution I can think of.